# counter part of __getattr__

Tags: python

I am trying to find a way to set `dict` values encapsulated into a `class`, for example using `__getattr__` i can return the internal `dict` value, however the `__setattr__` is called even when attributes exists, making my implementation ugly. The example below is simplified my actual class inherits from a `Subject` `class` (the subject part of the observer pattern)

i am trying to achieve something like this:

```
obj = Example()
obj.username = 'spidername' # all OK username is a key in the internal dict
# but company is not a key in the internal dict so
obj.company = 'ABC' # will raise AttributeError
```

and i am asking if there is a better way than the way i am doing below:

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, table=None):
        self._fields = {}
        self._table = table

    def _set_fields(self):
        """
        this method will be implemented by 
        subclasses and used to set fields names and values
        i.e.
        self._field['username'] = Field(default='unknown', is_primary=False)
        """
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """
        great this method is only called when "name"
        is not an attribute of this class
        """
        if name in self._fields:
            return self._fields[name].value
        return None

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        """
        not so great, this method is called even for
        attributes that exists in this class

        is there a better way to do the following?             
        this can be in __init__, but its still ugly
        """
        attribs = ['_fields', '_table'] 
        if name in attribs:
            super(Example, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        else:
            if name in self._fields:
                self._fields[name].value = value
            else:
                raise AttributeError
```

EDIT: adjusted comment in code, added missin quotes

Comment: An aside: there are already many good python libraries for doing Object Relational Mapping (ORM), for example SQLAlchemy; if thats what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks, yes i know, there is also Storm and SQLObject that i know of. but i like something simpler and that is my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the attributes don't exist when they are first assigned.  In `__init__`, when you first assign a dict to `_fields`, `_fields` is not an attribute.  It only becomes an existing attribute after its been assigned.  You could use `__slots__` if you know in advance what the attributes are, but my guess is that you don't.  So my suggestion would be to insert these into the instance dict manually:

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, table=None):
        self.__dict__['_fields'] = {}
        self.__dict__['_table'] = table

    ...

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in self._fields:
            self._fields[name].value = value
        else:
            raise AttributeError
```

However, with this implementation, the only way you can add or change instance attributes later would be through `__dict__`. But I assume this is not likely.

Comment: I don't think he would need the `hasattr` at all -- I didn't get the impression he needed to assign to them again outside `__init__` based on him saying "I know this could be in `__init__`" in his comment in `__setattr__`.

Comment: i tried `__slots__` first, but did not work, as `__setattr__` was still getting called, and that created a problem because inside `__setattr__` i would not know if `name` is referring to a legit class attribute set in `__init__` or a key in `self._fields`, your solution worked perfectly. the only thing, as also agf commented is that `hasattr` inside `__setattr__ is not needed anymore.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, your overall goal can be achieved directly just by using [*__slots__*](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots):

```
>>> class Example(object):
        __slots__ = ['username']

>>> obj = Example()
>>> obj.username = 'spiderman'
>>> obj.company = 'ABC'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    obj.company = 'ABC'
AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute 'company'
```

Comment: even using __slots__, __setattr__ is still called for each attribute, and i don't want that, i want __setattr__ to be called only when client code wants to set a value on the internal dict.